# adduser has no difference from useradd

Tags: fedora, useradd

When I use the adduser command on fedora, it's not aksing for password or fullname. 
It's working exactly like useradd. 
I don't understand why.

```
[hugues@localhost ~]$ sudo adduser user1
[hugues@localhost ~]$ sudo useradd user2
```

And it creates two users in /etc/passwd

```
user1:x:1004:1010::/home/user1:/bin/bash 
user2:x:1005:1011::/home/user2:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in fedora there is only `useradd` command, `adduser` is just a symlink to useradd.

you can check that with the following command:

```
ls -ld /usr/sbin/adduser
```

the output of the command:

```
[root@fedora28 ~]# ls -ld /usr/sbin/adduser
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Feb 6 05:37 /usr/sbin/adduser -> useradd
```

Comment: Could you please add the output of the command in your answer? (on Ubuntu `ls -ld /usr/sbin/adduser` and `ls -ld /usr/sbin/useradd` display files with different sizes, so I'm curious about the output on Fedora)

Comment: @A.L `adduser` is a symlink to `useradd`.

Comment: I had some vague recollection of there once-upon-a-time being a separate `adduser` command, and looked in the package changelog, which includes: `Mon Oct 27 1997: - obsolete adduser`. I guess I'm getting old. :)

Comment: @A.L i have added the output of `ls -ld` to the answer

Answer (score 0):

`useradd` is the only command of them two which is available on all Unix style systems (I know of).

On Debian and its derivatives, `adduser` is a wrapper to `useradd` which adds some comfort like generating a same named group by default.

In Fedora, they are the same.

Comment: `useradd` is not a POSIX utility, neither is `adduser`.